How do I get video events to fire
I'm having a problem with Google Chrome and Edge where no YouTube video events are occurring. I need to know when a video ends. I have used the code from YouTube's iFrame API. The events work properly in Safari.
Here is HTML and Javascript code:
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xPxk0zvqes4? enablejsapi=1&origin=https://mishparking.com"
        frameborder="0"></iframe>

var tag = document.createElement('script');

Javascript:
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        playerVars: {
            'playsinline': 1
         },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}


function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

    if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        alert("Video has ended.");
    }
}
function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
}


The only thing I see in OP is that the URL has a space before enablejsapi=1. When getting the value of event.data use it as a simple number instead of the .playerState property for the sake of brevity. The example below doesn't work on SO, so if you want to review a functioning example go to this fiddle.


const tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
const firstTag = document.querySelector("script");
firstTag.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", tag);

const view = document.querySelector("#message");

let ytPlayer;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  ytPlayer = new YT.Player("ytFrame", {
    events: {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady,
      "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  view.value = "Video is ready";
}

function playerStatus(status) {
  switch (status) {
    case 0:
      view.value = "Video has ended";
      break;
    case 1:
      view.value = "Video is playing";
      break;
    case 2:
      view.value = "Video is paused";
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  playerStatus(event.data);
}
#ytFrame {
  display: block;
}

#message {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 320px;
  height: 25px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  text-align: center;
  color: gold;
  background: black;
}
<iframe id="ytFrame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4r7wHMg5Yjg?enablejsapi=1" width="320" height="180" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<output id="message"></output>



